# What's wrong with TaskCompletionSource<DeploymentCatalog>?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, mono, mef, task-parallel-library

I am using the Nuget package [System.Threading.Tasks](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks) for Silverlight 4 (a port from Mono). I keep getting the `InvalidOperationException` ("The underlying Task is already in one of the three final states: RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled.") for the following:

```
var tasks = new Task<DeploymentCatalog>[2];

//Catalog the XAP downloaded by the Application Loader, the BiggestBox Index:
var uri0 = new Uri(Application.Current.

Host.InitParams["LoaderInfoXapPath"], UriKind.Relative);
tasks[0] = CompositionUtility.DownloadCatalogAsync(uri0);

//Catalog the XAP with the BiggestBox Index Part:
var uri1 = new Uri(Application.Current
    .Host.InitParams["BiggestBoxIndexXapPath"], UriKind.Relative);
tasks[1] = CompositionUtility.DownloadCatalogAsync(uri1);

//tasks did not run by default...
//tasks[0].Start();
//tasks[1].Start();

Task.WaitAll(tasks);

this.AddToAggregateCatalog(tasks[0].Result);
this.AddToAggregateCatalog(tasks[1].Result);

base.Compose();
```

where `DownloadCatalogAsync` is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Downloads the catalog
/// in a <see cref="System.Threading.Task"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="location">The location.</param>
/// <param name="downloadCompleteAction">The download complete action.</param>
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000:DisposeObjectsBeforeLosingScope",
    Justification = "Reliable disposal depends on callers.")]
public static Task<DeploymentCatalog> DownloadCatalogAsync(Uri location)
{
    return DownloadCatalogAsTask(location, null);
}

/// <summary>
/// Downloads the catalog
/// in a <see cref="System.Threading.Task"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="location">The location.</param>
/// <param name="downloadCompleteAction">The download complete action.</param>
/// <remarks>
/// For details, see the “Converting an Event-Based Pattern” section in 
/// “Simplify Asynchronous Programming with Tasks”
/// by Igor Ostrovsky
/// [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff959203.aspx]
/// </remarks>
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000:DisposeObjectsBeforeLosingScope",
    Justification = "Reliable disposal depends on callers.")]
public static Task<DeploymentCatalog> DownloadCatalogAsync(Uri location,
    Action<object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> downloadCompleteAction)
{
    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<DeploymentCatalog>();
    var catalog = new DeploymentCatalog(location);

    catalog.DownloadCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        if(args.Error != null) completionSource.SetException(args.Error);
        else if(args.Cancelled) completionSource.SetCanceled();
        else
        {
            completionSource.SetResult(s as DeploymentCatalog); //exception thrown here
            if(downloadCompleteAction != null)
                downloadCompleteAction.Invoke(s, args);
        }
    };

    catalog.DownloadAsync();

    return completionSource.Task;
}
```

I use this same pattern with `WebClient` and it works fine (but I don't have to `Start()` the tasks explicitly---however I did not test `WebClient` with the Mono-ported version of Task Parallel Library (for Silverlight). I guess I should do that...

Answer (score 3):

You're calling Start on the TaskCompletionSource and the TCS Task had already started and, in the case when you get this exception, it already completed too. Generally you want to design methods like DownloadCatalogAsTask to return already started Task instances and callers can expect them to be started and avoid calling Start themselves.

Couple other suggestions:

1. I would consider renaming the method to DownloadCatalogAsync to align with .NET 4.5 naming guidelines.
2. I would not pass the Action<> into the async method. The whole point of returning a Task is so that you can chain on continuations using familiar patterns like an explicit ContinueWith or the await keyword in C# 5.0. Here you're inventing you own approach.

Comment: I will take these new 4.5 conventions to heart. I failed to mention that I'm using Silverlight 4 with a Mono port of TPL. Sadly, I had to call `Start()` explicitly otherwise the Tasks would return `WaitingForActivation`---this unexpected behavior might have something to do with this Mono stuff?

Comment: @rasx It's ok that you have to call Start, just make sure you start it within the method that returns the Task instead of leaving it up to the consumer to have to start it. As far as the behavior goes, yes it's because of the approach you've had to take with Silverlight + the Mono TPL library. In .NET 4 TPL you would be more likely to just use Task.Factory.StartNew.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. i.e. Mono TPL on Silverlight 4; exception thrown at `completionSource.SetResult()`.

This was resolved when I used `completionSource.TrySetResult()` instead.